# Formatting HTTP headers using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, string, http, http-headers

I want to format my HTTP headers using regex. I've done it using `split(' ')` followed by array manipulation, however this time I want to perform this operation using regex.

I want to take this input which is a giant string:

```
GET /v1/search?q=bob%20dylan&amp;type=artist HTTP/1.1
Host: api.spotify.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: e2f09f98-f8e0-43f7-5f0e-b16e670399e2
```

and format it to be an object as so:

```
{ headers: 
   { Host: ' api.spotify.com',
     'Cache-Control': ' no-cache',
     'Postman-Token': ' e2f09f98-f8e0-43f7-5f0e-b16e670399e2' 
   },
  verb: 'GET',
  path: '/v1/search?q=bob%20dylan&amp;type=artist',
  protocol: 'HTTP/1.1' 
}
```

I understand by using the `split` method, my code is more readable. However, my first attempt was to use regex since my goal was to extract/format a string.

I know it is possible through regex, but is it even worth it? What does everyone think?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you:

```js
const data = `GET /v1/search?q=bob%20dylan&amp;type=artist HTTP/1.1
Host: api.spotify.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: e2f09f98-f8e0-43f7-5f0e-b16e670399e2`

const format = data => {
    const headers = {}
    const result = { headers }
    const regex = /([\w-]+): (.*)/g
    let temp
    while (temp = regex.exec(data)) {
        headers[temp[1]] = temp[2]
    }
    temp = data.match(/(\w+)\s+(.*?)\s+(.*)/)
    result.verb = temp[1]
    result.path = temp[2]
    result.protocol = temp[3]
    return result
}

console.log(format(data))
```

`/([\w-]+): (.*)/g` this  regex will match any `header-name: value` and capture it like so `['header-name: value', 'header-name', 'value']`

then we asign it to `headers` object where `header-name` is `key` and `value` is `value`

at the end we parse first line to get rest of information

### How it works

`(\w+)` match and capture 1 or more word characters
`\s+` match 1 or more whitespace
`(.*?)`match and capture any char **not gready** `*?`
`\s+`  until one or more white space is found
`(.*)` match evrything (until end of line)

Comment: What is `/(\w+)\s+(.*?)\s+(.*)/` doing here? I can't seem to follow after the first `(\w+)` . It's looking for 1 or more words followed by 1 or more spaces `\s+` followed by `(.*?)`?

Comment: I'll write explanation.

Comment: I added toLowerCase() for the headers keys for a compatibility issue with nodejs http style requests, but this works well. Also httpVersion not protocol, path is originally there called 'url', and verb is 'method' traditionally in node as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.split()` with `RegExp` `\s/` where the first three elements of array returned by `.split()` should be `verb`, `path`, `protocol`; utilize `.shift()` on first three elements, with the remainder of results  set as property, value pairs at `headers` object using current index and next index of array, until array `.length` evaluates to `false` at condition of  `while` loop.

```js
let getHeaders = headers => {

  let h = headers.split(/\s/);

  let o = {
    verb: h.shift(),
    path: h.shift(),
    protocol: h.shift(),
    headers: {}
  };

  while (h.length) {
    o.headers[h.shift()] = h.shift();
  }
  
  return o
};

var str = `GET /v1/search?q=bob%20dylan&amp;type=artist HTTP/1.1
Host: api.spotify.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: e2f09f98-f8e0-43f7-5f0e-b16e670399e2`;

console.log(getHeaders(str));
```

Comment: Not working right with this example but I like what you did.
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.2.174
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

Answer (score 0):

This Should Work.

Search by:

```
(GET)\s(.+)\s(HTTP\/\d+\.\d+)\n(Host):\s(.+)$\n(Cache-Control):\s(.+)$\n(Postman-Token):\s(.+)$
```

Replace with:

```
{ headers:    \n\t{ $4 '$5',\n\t  '$6': '$7',\n\t  '$8': '$9'\n\t}, \n\tverb: '$1',\n\tpath: '$2',\n\tprotocol: '$3'\n}
```

JavaScript Code:

```js
const regex = /(GET)\s(.+)\s(HTTP\/\d+\.\d+)\n(Host):\s(.+)$\n(Cache-Control):\s(.+)$\n(Postman-Token):\s(.+)$/gm;
const str = `GET /v1/search?q=bob%20dylan&amp;type=artist HTTP/1.1
Host: api.spotify.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: e2f09f98-f`;
const subst = `{ headers:    \n\t{ \$4 '\$5',\n\t  '\$6': '\$7',\n\t  '\$8': '\$9'\n\t}, \n\tverb: '\$1',\n\tpath: '\$2',\n\tprotocol: '\$3'\\n}`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

Input:

```
GET /v1/search?q=bob%20dylan&amp;type=artist HTTP/1.1
Host: api.spotify.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: e2f09f98-f
```

Output:

```
{ headers:    
    { Host 'api.spotify.com',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
      'Postman-Token': 'e2f09f98-f'
    }, 
    verb: 'GET',
    path: '/v1/search?q=bob%20dylan&amp;type=artist',
    protocol: 'HTTP/1.1'
}
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/3DKEas/4